# OAuth2.createService calls to PropertiesService takes too long, sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, gmail

Using [OAuth2 Library 1.35.0](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) and Gmail API V1 (https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/settings/delegates) in a Google Apps Script to get the delegates of a mailbox and I am getting some weird response times specifically from the 
PropertiesService.Properties.setProperty and PropertiesService.Properties.deleteProperty calls using:

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic';
email = 'delegator@domain.com';

```
function getOAuthService(email,scope) {
  return OAuth2.createService("gmail")
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setPrivateKey(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
  .setIssuer(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL)
  .setSubject(email)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
  .setScope(scope);
}
```

Running the script against a single mailbox the total runtime is 0.783 seconds
Running the same script against 20 mailboxes results in a 67.203 seconds total runtime and the only noticeable cause is the following calls:
PropertiesService.Properties.deleteProperty([oauth2.gmail]) [9.062 seconds]
PropertiesService.Properties.setProperty([oauth2.gmail,access_token:”…”) [11.086 seconds]
PropertiesService.Properties.deleteProperty([oauth2.gmail]) [7.061 seconds]
PropertiesService.Properties.setProperty([oauth2.gmail,access_token:”…”) [9.089 seconds]
PropertiesService.Properties.deleteProperty([oauth2.gmail]) [9.052 seconds]
PropertiesService.Properties.setProperty([oauth2.gmail,access_token:”…”) [9.087 seconds]

Out of a total runtime of 67.203 seconds 54.437 seconds is taken up by the above 6 calls.
There are a total of 80 calls to the PropertiesService.Properties. (get/set/delete) with the rest (74) of them executing in a combined total of  3.972 seconds at an average of less than 0.06 each.

This is test run on a subset of data and when I run this on all of the data my script times out.
60 mailboxes takes 239.716 seconds

Strangely enough I don't get the same issue when running it against

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';
APIs: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages and https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id

Any advice?

Comment: Are you providing your full code? I cannot see in your code e.g. `PropertiesService.Properties.deleteProperty`. This is not a valid request (maybe you mean `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty(key)`?) Also, where in your code is this line?

Comment: [OAuth2](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) for Apps Script is a library for Google Apps Script that provides the ability to create and authorise OAuth2 tokens as well as refresh them when they expire. It is this library that takes care of the PropertiesService and I cannot change it.

Comment: The problem about this library is that it is an external service. Also, getting and setting script properties is an external call. I am not sure why using different scopes reduces your execution time, but in general, external calls make your code slow, see here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services If you want to make your code faster - either do not use a service account (if possible) and thus avoid OAuth2, or - use a different programming language where you won't need an external library to set-up a service account.

Comment: Sorry took a while to come back to this but I have stopped calling the external library by moving the whole Oauth2 script file into the Apps script, removing the library and calling the functions directly. I am still getting excessive times on the PropertiesService.Properties.setProperty calls

Comment: `.setProperty` is still an external call that is time consuming. Try to set several properties in one go with `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(properties)`